# Strange behavior in circular textbox wpf project

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have this page in a WPF project in Visual Studio 2013

[image]

but when I execute it, it show this:

[image]

If I maximize it, it show this:

[image]

this is the XAML page code:

```
<Page x:Class="ControlDomotico.Client.MenuPrincipal"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
  mc:Ignorable="d"
Title="MenuPrincipal" d:DesignHeight="633.654" d:DesignWidth="877.835">

<Grid>
    <Grid.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="d:\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\ControlDomotico\ControlDomotico.Client\images\menu.jpg">
            <ImageBrush.Transform>
                <TransformGroup>
                    <ScaleTransform ScaleY="1.05"/>
                    <SkewTransform/>
                    <RotateTransform/>
                    <TranslateTransform X="-11"/>
                </TransformGroup>
            </ImageBrush.Transform>
        </ImageBrush>
    </Grid.Background>
    <Label Content="Bienvenido a tu casa" FontSize="30px" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="10.453,3.723" Height="53" Width="309" Margin="10,10,0,0" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Background="#00000000" Foreground="#FF0F0101" FontWeight="Bold"/>

    <Button Name="claveBtn" Width="100" Content="Cambiar clave"
    Height="100" Margin="439,40,339,493.6" >
        <Button.Template>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Grid>
                    <Ellipse Stroke="Black"
                     StrokeThickness="2">
                        <Ellipse.Fill>
                            <RadialGradientBrush>
                                <GradientStop Offset="0"
                                      Color="Gold" />
                                <GradientStop Offset="1"
                                      Color="Gold" />
                                <GradientStop Offset="1"
                                      Color="Gold" />
                                <RadialGradientBrush.Transform>
                                    <TransformGroup>
                                        <ScaleTransform ScaleY="0.65" />
                                    </TransformGroup>
                                </RadialGradientBrush.Transform>
                            </RadialGradientBrush>
                        </Ellipse.Fill>
                    </Ellipse>
                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                              VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Button.Template>
    </Button>
    <Button Name="alarmaBtn" Width="100" Content="Configurar alarma"
        Height="100" Margin="588,95,190,438.6">
        <Button.Template>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Grid>
                    <Ellipse Stroke="Black"
                        StrokeThickness="2">
                        <Ellipse.Fill>
                            <RadialGradientBrush>
                                <RadialGradientBrush.Transform>
                                    <TransformGroup>
                                        <ScaleTransform ScaleY="0.65" />
                                    </TransformGroup>
                                </RadialGradientBrush.Transform>
                                <GradientStop Offset="0"
                                    Color="Gold" />
                                <GradientStop Offset="1"
                                    Color="Gold" />
                                <GradientStop Offset="1"
                                    Color="Gold" />
                            </RadialGradientBrush>
                        </Ellipse.Fill>
                    </Ellipse>
                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                        VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Button.Template>
    </Button>
    <Button Name="horaBtn" Width="100" Content="Cambiar hora"
        Height="100" Margin="732,198,46,335.6" Click="horaBtn_Click">
        <Button.Template>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Grid>
                    <Ellipse Stroke="Black"
                        StrokeThickness="2">
                        <Ellipse.Fill>
                            <RadialGradientBrush>
                                <RadialGradientBrush.Transform>
                                    <TransformGroup>
                                        <ScaleTransform ScaleY="0.65" />
                                    </TransformGroup>
                                </RadialGradientBrush.Transform>
                                <GradientStop Offset="0"
                                    Color="Gold" />
                                <GradientStop Offset="1"
                                    Color="Gold" />
                                <GradientStop Offset="1"
                                    Color="Gold" />
                            </RadialGradientBrush>
                        </Ellipse.Fill>
                    </Ellipse>
                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                        VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Button.Template>
    </Button>
    <Button Name="puertaBtn" Width="100" Content="Puerta"
        Height="100" Margin="607,308,171,225.6">
        <Button.Template>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Grid>
                    <Ellipse Stroke="Black"
                        StrokeThickness="2">
                        <Ellipse.Fill>
                            <RadialGradientBrush>
                                <RadialGradientBrush.Transform>
                                    <TransformGroup>
                                        <ScaleTransform ScaleY="0.65" />
                                    </TransformGroup>
                                </RadialGradientBrush.Transform>
                                <GradientStop Offset="0"
                                    Color="Gold" />
                                <GradientStop Offset="1"
                                    Color="Gold" />
                                <GradientStop Offset="1"
                                    Color="Gold" />
                            </RadialGradientBrush>
                        </Ellipse.Fill>
                    </Ellipse>
                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                        VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Button.Template>
    </Button>
    <Button Name="iluminacionBtn" Width="100" Content="Iluminación"
        Height="100" Margin="588,463,190,70.6">
        <Button.Template>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Grid>
                    <Ellipse Stroke="Black"
                        StrokeThickness="2">
                        <Ellipse.Fill>
                            <RadialGradientBrush>
                                <RadialGradientBrush.Transform>
                                    <TransformGroup>
                                        <ScaleTransform ScaleY="0.65" />
                                    </TransformGroup>
                                </RadialGradientBrush.Transform>
                                <GradientStop Offset="0"
                                    Color="Gold" />
                                <GradientStop Offset="1"
                                    Color="Gold" />
                                <GradientStop Offset="1"
                                    Color="Gold" />
                            </RadialGradientBrush>
                        </Ellipse.Fill>
                    </Ellipse>
                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                        VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Button.Template>
    </Button>
    <Button Name="baneraBtn" Width="100" Content="Bañera"
        Height="100" Margin="439,508,339,25.6">
        <Button.Template>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Grid>
                    <Ellipse Stroke="Black"
                        StrokeThickness="2">
                        <Ellipse.Fill>
                            <RadialGradientBrush>
                                <RadialGradientBrush.Transform>
                                    <TransformGroup>
                                        <ScaleTransform ScaleY="0.65" />
                                    </TransformGroup>
                                </RadialGradientBrush.Transform>
                                <GradientStop Offset="0"
                                    Color="Gold" />
                                <GradientStop Offset="1"
                                    Color="Gold" />
                                <GradientStop Offset="1"
                                    Color="Gold" />
                            </RadialGradientBrush>
                        </Ellipse.Fill>
                    </Ellipse>
                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                        VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Button.Template>
    </Button>
</Grid>
```

I dont understand this behavior, can help me with that please?

Comment: What is happening is that you are setting a size for you buttons of 100 x 100 when you shrink your form it is causing the available space for your button to shrink , but your button has a static size therefore the clipping. Consider setting your Window's `MinHeight` and `MaxHeight` properties to prevent the Window being stretched to small, or you can see if enclosing your `Grid` in a `ViewBox` will work for you.

Comment: Try to remove any padding or margin set both horizontal and vertical alignment to zero. May help you

Comment: I have tried both, but nothing work

Comment: If you cannot figure out an appropriate fix for the code based on the comments about, then please provide [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reliably reproduces the problem. Without one, there's too much guesswork to make it worth anyone's while to try to write up an actual code solution for an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Size of the Window clashes with the margins that you have set on the `Buttons` for some reason. I would advise that you design your code in the XAML editor using `RowDefinitions` & `Column Definitions` on the `Grid` rather than in the XAML designer. However a quick-fix to your solution would be:

a: Increase the `Window/Page` size to `833 x 933` or something similar.

b: Enclose your code in a `ViewBox` like so:

```
<Viewbox>
    <Grid Background="Red">

        <Label Content="Bienvenido a tu casa" FontSize="30px" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="10.453,3.723" Height="53" Width="309" Margin="10,10,0,0" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Background="#00000000" Foreground="#FF0F0101" FontWeight="Bold"/>

        <Button Name="claveBtn" Width="100" Content="Cambiar clave"
    Height="100" Margin="664,445.5,106,257.5"  >
            <Button.Template>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Grid>
                        <Ellipse Stroke="Black"
                     StrokeThickness="2">
                            <Ellipse.Fill>
                                <RadialGradientBrush>
                                    <GradientStop Offset="0"
                                      Color="Gold" />
                                    <GradientStop Offset="1"
                                      Color="Gold" />
                                    <GradientStop Offset="1"
                                      Color="Gold" />
                                    <RadialGradientBrush.Transform>
                                        <TransformGroup>
                                            <ScaleTransform ScaleY="0.65" />
                                        </TransformGroup>
                                    </RadialGradientBrush.Transform>
                                </RadialGradientBrush>
                            </Ellipse.Fill>
                        </Ellipse>
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                              VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Button.Template>
        </Button>
        <Button Name="alarmaBtn"  ClipToBounds="True" Content="Configurar alarma" Width="100" Height="100" Click="alarmaBtn_Click" Margin="581,103.55,189,599.45">
            <Button.Template>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Ellipse Stroke="Black"
                        StrokeThickness="2">
                            <Ellipse.Fill>
                                <RadialGradientBrush>
                                    <RadialGradientBrush.Transform>
                                        <TransformGroup>
                                            <ScaleTransform ScaleY="0.65" />
                                        </TransformGroup>
                                    </RadialGradientBrush.Transform>
                                    <GradientStop Offset="0"
                                    Color="Gold" />
                                    <GradientStop Offset="1"
                                    Color="Gold" />
                                    <GradientStop Offset="1"
                                    Color="Gold" />
                                </RadialGradientBrush>
                            </Ellipse.Fill>
                        </Ellipse>
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                        VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Button.Template>
        </Button>
        <Button Name="horaBtn" Width="100" Content="Cambiar hora"
        Height="100" Margin="485,597.5,285,105.5"  >
            <Button.Template>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Ellipse Stroke="Black"
                        StrokeThickness="2">
                            <Ellipse.Fill>
                                <RadialGradientBrush>
                                    <RadialGradientBrush.Transform>
                                        <TransformGroup>
                                            <ScaleTransform ScaleY="0.65" />
                                        </TransformGroup>
                                    </RadialGradientBrush.Transform>
                                    <GradientStop Offset="0"
                                    Color="Gold" />
                                    <GradientStop Offset="1"
                                    Color="Gold" />
                                    <GradientStop Offset="1"
                                    Color="Gold" />
                                </RadialGradientBrush>
                            </Ellipse.Fill>
                        </Ellipse>
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                        VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Button.Template>
        </Button>
        <Button Name="puertaBtn" Width="100" Content="Puerta"
        Height="100" Margin="689,236.5,81,466.5" >
            <Button.Template>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Ellipse Stroke="Black"
                        StrokeThickness="2">
                            <Ellipse.Fill>
                                <RadialGradientBrush>
                                    <RadialGradientBrush.Transform>
                                        <TransformGroup>
                                            <ScaleTransform ScaleY="0.65" />
                                        </TransformGroup>
                                    </RadialGradientBrush.Transform>
                                    <GradientStop Offset="0"
                                    Color="Gold" />
                                    <GradientStop Offset="1"
                                    Color="Gold" />
                                    <GradientStop Offset="1"
                                    Color="Gold" />
                                </RadialGradientBrush>
                            </Ellipse.Fill>
                        </Ellipse>
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                        VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Button.Template>
        </Button>
        <Button Name="iluminacionBtn" Width="100" Content="Iluminación"
        Height="100" Margin="385,58.5,385,644.5" >
            <Button.Template>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Ellipse Stroke="Black"
                        StrokeThickness="2">
                            <Ellipse.Fill>
                                <RadialGradientBrush>
                                    <RadialGradientBrush.Transform>
                                        <TransformGroup>
                                            <ScaleTransform ScaleY="0.65" />
                                        </TransformGroup>
                                    </RadialGradientBrush.Transform>
                                    <GradientStop Offset="0"
                                    Color="Gold" />
                                    <GradientStop Offset="1"
                                    Color="Gold" />
                                    <GradientStop Offset="1"
                                    Color="Gold" />
                                </RadialGradientBrush>
                            </Ellipse.Fill>
                        </Ellipse>
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                        VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Button.Template>
        </Button>
        <Button Name="baneraBtn" Width="100" Content="Bañera"
        Height="100" Margin="204,629.5,566,73.5" >
            <Button.Template>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Ellipse Stroke="Black"
                        StrokeThickness="2">
                            <Ellipse.Fill>
                                <RadialGradientBrush>
                                    <RadialGradientBrush.Transform>
                                        <TransformGroup>
                                            <ScaleTransform ScaleY="0.65" />
                                        </TransformGroup>
                                    </RadialGradientBrush.Transform>
                                    <GradientStop Offset="0"
                                    Color="Gold" />
                                    <GradientStop Offset="1"
                                    Color="Gold" />
                                    <GradientStop Offset="1"
                                    Color="Gold" />
                                </RadialGradientBrush>
                            </Ellipse.Fill>
                        </Ellipse>
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                        VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Button.Template>
        </Button>
    </Grid>
    </Viewbox>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using margins and fixed size buttons, you should divide your panel into hypothetical grid areas like this image:

[image]

Then for example *"Cambiar clave"* is located in `Grid.Row = 0  Grid.Column = 1` or as for *"Puerta"* it's `Grid.Row = 3  Grid.Column = 2` and so on. This can be done like this:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="d:\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\ControlDomotico\ControlDomotico.Client\images\menu.jpg">
            <ImageBrush.Transform>
                <TransformGroup>
                    <ScaleTransform ScaleY="1.05"/>
                    <SkewTransform/>
                    <RotateTransform/>
                    <TranslateTransform X="-11"/>
                </TransformGroup>
            </ImageBrush.Transform>
        </ImageBrush>
    </Grid.Background>
    <Label Content="Bienvenido a tu casa" FontSize="30px" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="10.453,3.723" Height="53" Width="309" Margin="10,10,0,0" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Background="#00000000" Foreground="#FF0F0101" FontWeight="Bold"/>
    <Button Name="claveBtn"  Content="Cambiar clave"
     Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Template="{StaticResource RoundButton}"/>
    <Button Name="alarmaBtn"  Content="Configurar alarma"
     Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Template="{StaticResource RoundButton}"/>
    <Button Name="horaBtn" Content="Cambiar hora"
     Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="3" Template="{StaticResource RoundButton}" />
    <Button Name="puertaBtn" Content="Puerta"
     Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="2" Template="{StaticResource RoundButton}"/>
    <Button Name="iluminacionBtn"  Content="Iluminación"
     Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="2" Template="{StaticResource RoundButton}"/>
    <Button Name="baneraBtn" Content="Bañera"
     Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="1" Template="{StaticResource RoundButton}"/>
</Grid>
```

You should also define your `ControlTemplate` (I called it `RoundButton`) in resource section to avoid code duplication:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="RoundButton" TargetType="Button">
        <Grid>
            <Ellipse Stroke="Black"
                 StrokeThickness="2">
                <Ellipse.Fill>
                    <RadialGradientBrush>
                        <GradientStop Offset="0"
                                  Color="Gold" />
                        <GradientStop Offset="1"
                                  Color="Gold" />
                        <GradientStop Offset="1"
                                  Color="Gold" />
                        <RadialGradientBrush.Transform>
                            <TransformGroup>
                                <ScaleTransform ScaleY="0.65" />
                            </TransformGroup>
                        </RadialGradientBrush.Transform>
                    </RadialGradientBrush>
                </Ellipse.Fill>
            </Ellipse>
            <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                          VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>
</Page.Resources>
```